# Extracting day,month,2-digits year from text in Google Sheets using Regexextract

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

would appreciate any help.

This is how the text looks like `11jun2018/M` , `16JUL1976/F`(it's date of birth+male or female)

I need to get the next result: `11jun18` , `16jul76`.

I tried `\d{2}\w{3}\d{4}` which results in `11jun2018` and i also found what `\d{2}(\d{2})` results in `18` ,but i can't figure out how to unite those two regex.

Because when i unite,i get previous result(only `18`,instead of `11jun18`).

Would also appreciate some regex guide for dummies

Comment: I suspect you have data like 1aug2018? Or is that also formatted as 01aug2018?

Comment: Yeah,sry,forgot to mention that,it's in a second format,including (zero),like you wrote 01aug2018

Comment: In that case I don't see a need for regular expressions to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
=LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^(\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3})\d{2}(\d{2})/[MF]$", "$1$2"))
```

If there must be an empty result if there is no match add `|.+` at the end:

```
=LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^(\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3})\d{2}(\d{2})/[MF]$|.+", "$1$2"))
```

Here,

- `^` - matches start of string
- `(\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3})` - captures 2 digits and 3 letters into Group 1 (`$1`)
- `\d{2}` - matches two digits
- `(\d{2})` - captures two digits into Group 2 (`$2`)
- `/` - a slash
- `[MF]` - `M` or `F` is matched
- `$` - end of string
- `|.+` - or matches any other string, 1 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you,it works.But i need to use it in a formula and want everything to look as simple as it can be.Is it possible to somehow unite what i tried to get the result?

Comment: @ValeraLexiutchin I *am* using a formula. I *have* "united" what you had into one.

Comment: Thank you again,i finally figured it out and also tried other things thx to you.I want to write what i tried.Should i do it here or should I edit Question so it will be more visible for others when they first time open the page?Sorry for asking too much,i am kinda new here.

Comment: @ValeraLexiutchin Add your own answer if it is a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

[image]

The formula used:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(REPLACE(LOWER(FILTER(A1:A,A1:A<>"")),6,2,),7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tnx to Wiktor Stribiżew formula i tried some more things and here that i came up with:

1.I did what I wanted from the start,unite my 2 regex: `\d{2}\w{3}\d{4}` and `\d{2}(\d{2})` into `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\d{2}\w{3})\d{2}(\d{2})")` 
but it wrote answer into 2 cells(B51,C51) as you can see on screenshot.

[image]

-I want to remind that cell C51 doesn't contain any formula.

We can just divide formula from B51 into two regexextract formulas and concatenate them.

Like this `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d{2}\w{3}")&REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d{2}(\d{2})")`

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d{2}\w{3}")` results in **06JUL** and `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\d{2}(\d{2})")` results in **77**

See the Link for Google Sheets below

2.If you don't like the first method we can also do this:

Since we are getting response with array from REGEXEXTRACT function we can just get rid of it using function **JOIN** or **TEXTJOIN**

`=JOIN("",REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\d{2}\w{3})\d{2}(\d{2})"))`

I decided to better give link to [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11pFV7Zr_fXNYojbTwV2feZSBrp1etmLn9NP1jQAeqkY/edit?usp=sharing) for whose who are interested in checking solution I mentioned above, instead of making ton of screenshots.